# Blazor Navbar not displaying properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio, blazor

I can't get navbar to expand across the page as I program this Visual Studio 2019 Blazor application. Have tried many different variations of this code all with failed results.

My MainLayout.razor page:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div>
    <NavMenu />
</div>
<div class="content px-4">
    @Body
</div>
```

My NavMenu.razor page:

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar bg-dark navbar-dark navbar-expand-sm">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Schedule</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Other Stuff</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

However the navbar appears like this when I run the application:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try not putting the navbar inside a container, like this:

```
<nav class="navbar bg-dark navbar-dark navbar-expand-sm">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Schedule</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Other Stuff</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Actually I have figured out that the determining factor is in the MainLayout.razor code. I have change it to                                                                                                               `<div class="bg-danger container-fluid">
    <NavMenu />
</div>
<div class="content px-4">
    @Body
</div>`  to test and the alert fills almost the entire page while the navbar tits in the container offset 15 px ..

Answer (score 0):

If your using bootstrap you should look at [flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/flex/)

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div class="d-flex flex-row">
    <NavMenu />
</div>
<div class="content px-4">
    @Body
</div>
```

```
<div class="navbar navbar-light flex-fill">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Schedule</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Other Stuff</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this yields the same results. I double-checked by changing to navbar-dark to test as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've traced the problem down to the css in the MainLayout.razor page. Since this question has diverted from what I thought the original problem was, I am going to create a new question that is more focused on that piece of code.